# Django form fields don't appear in my html render page

Tags: python, html, django, forms

i have a problem in my django project. Im quite new and im try to create a base form to create a new item in my database.

this is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Progetto
       
class Myprogetto(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
               model = Progetto
               fields = ['nome', 'descrizione', 'data_inizio', 'data_fine']
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Progetto
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import Myprogetto

def aggiungi_progetto(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Myprogetto(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  
            nome = form.cleaned_data['nome']
            Myprogetto_object=form.save(commit=False)
            Myprogetto_object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    else:
        form = Myprogetto()
    return render(request, 'lista_progetti.html', {"form": form})
```

this is my lista_progetti.html

> ```
>         <form id="popUpForm" display="none" action="" method="post">
>     
>             {% csrf_token %}
>             {{ form.as_p }}
>             
>             <input type="submit" value="Salva">
>         </form>
> ```

the problem is that when i lauch the server the form appear empty with just the button <salva>. I added a screenshot.

[image: my form view in html render]

Anyone can help me?

i tried to use both forms.ModelForm class and forms.Form class but the result is the same. I also try to write a simple form in html using html syntax and the fields appears but then i have problems in django to send the data to database cause it ask me to put the csrf_token.